# Eclipse PHP PDT Vaildation issues with required files

Tags: php, eclipse, warnings, require, eclipse-pdt

I am trying to setup eclipse Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0) 
but the problems window is being less than helpful. 
I have tried adding the projects sub folders to its build path & include path
and changing the order around without luck and deleting & recreating 
the project.

The current PDT options for my project are as follows:

```
Source paths
        Build path:
              project_folder -> Include all
        Include path:
              (Source) project_folder
```

Code assist is already set to show vars from other files
totally skipping the require checks

[Code assist option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afsWp.png)
and works at hinting the value names but the vaildator
has no idea whats going on and does not seem to follow the require_once
to each file

Example

```
index.php
     require_once 'system/global_vars.php';
     require_once 'site/rendering/main.php';
```

[The warnings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKRIe.png)

Any ideas on how to get Eclipse to follow include / requires 
or to force it some other way.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. It seems, PDT does not support this, see https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1094029/.

I assume you can define the variable in your index.php (at least it works for includes):

```
/**
 * Set in site/rendering/main.php
 * @var mixed $page (your var name)
 */
$page = null;
```